# How to loop over subdirectories and perform action while ignoring spaces in file names

Tags: bash, shell, for

I have the below folder structure in Linux env:

```
|-- Fixed_Zip
|   |-- ipython_notebooks
|   |   |-- notebook editor for compute_0anXhGEj.ipynb
|   |   |-- notebook editor for compute_aucScores.ipynb
|   |   |-- notebook editor for compute_nG27bM3w.ipynb
|   |   |-- notebook editor for compute_test_scored_scikit1.ipynb
```

as you can see, I have file names with spaces. How can I loop thought all the subdirectories in `Fixed_Zip` folder, and perform the command:
`jupytext --to py {file}` ?

One more thing, I'm doing the command from groovy file, so I guess there are some syntax to adjust.
I was able to run the below in my private env and it's working:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for i in `find . -name '*.ipynb' -type f`; do
                jupytext --to py "$i"
            done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

However, when I did the same in the groovy file:

```
sh '''
    SAVEIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$(echo -en "\\n\\b")
    for i in `find . -name '*.ipynb' -type f`; do
        jupytext --to py "$i"
    done
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
'''
```

I got the below error:

```
    raise InconsistentPath(
jupytext.paired_paths.InconsistentPath: './ipytho' is not a notebook.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Filenames with spaces" cries out for `find` and `xargs`. Read `man find xargs` and do something like

```
find Fixed_Zip -type f -name '*.ipynb' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r -n 1 jupytext --to py
```